# using require("") in angular/ts

Tags: angular, typescript, require

**EDITED**

this library doesn't have @types defined so i've created a `decs.d.ts` file with a fake definition in order don't make angular complain about that

```
declare module 'gitrows' {
    const x: any;
    export = x; 
}
```

https://github.com/gitrows/gitrows

then i can't using this library inside a component, i've tryed include it directly into the component's oninit event

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const gitrows = require('gitrows');
```

or on top of the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const gitrows = require('gitrows');
```

then when i use it, i get this error
`Gitrows is not a constructor`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const gr = new gitrows();
```

================================================================

**EDITED
trying to include  the library with**

```
import * as gitrows from 'gitrows'
console.log(gitrows)
```

./node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:9:22-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\PROGETTI\Personali\angular-crud-app\node_modules\csv-parse\lib'

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

Comment: have you tried  `import * as gitrows from 'gitrows'` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler same erroro: Gitrows is not a constructor

Comment: try console.log and see what's gitrows look like?

Comment: it's a package for nodeJs?

Comment: @vicnoob their site states "GitRows works with node and in any modern browser" so i suppose it can run clientside as well

Comment: @vicnoob i edited the post after tryed with `console.log`